# How to override attribute accessors with Rails reader method cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Many gems override Rails' attribute accessors using code like this:

```
define_method "#{dynamic_name}" do
  value = read_attribute(dynamic_name)
  # Do stuff
end
```

Or this:

```
belongs_to :user
def user
  # Do stuff
end
```

Rails 4.2 introduced a cache for atttribute methods (`AttributeMethodCache`, `ReaderMethodCache`, https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15429)

This results in wrong values when accessing the overriden attributes using the methods above. It looks like the return values from original reader methods are cached and returned even after overriding the method.

What is the recommended procedure to override attribute accessors in Rails 4.2?

Comment: So you need something like cleaning attribute cache?

Comment: If that is the recommended/preferred way then yes. I can imagine there is a way to exempt attributes from being cached, too.

Comment: I'm currently investigating this. I have a gut feeling that the behaviour I'm seeing is a side effect, possibly from another gem...

Comment: This is definitely a side effect. I cannot reproduce the problem with a new Rails application. Close-voting my own question because of irrelevance now.